# How can I sort a boxplot in pandas by the median values?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I want to draw a boxplot of column `Z` in dataframe `df` by the categories `X` and `Y`. How can I sort the boxplot by the median, in descending order?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
n = 100
# this is probably a strange way to generate random data; please feel free to correct it
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": [random.choice(["A","B","C"]) for i in range(n)], 
                   "Y": [random.choice(["a","b","c"]) for i in range(n)],
                   "Z": [random.gauss(0,1) for i in range(n)]})
df.boxplot(column="Z", by=["X", "Y"])
```

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469568/how-to-sort-a-boxplot-by-the-median-values-in-pandas/19471613#19471613) is very similar, but they use a different data structure. I'm relatively new to pandas (and have only done some tutorials on python in general), so I couldn't figure out how to make my data work with the answer posted there. This may well be more of a reshaping than a plotting question. Maybe there is a solution using `groupby`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the answer in [How to sort a boxplot by the median values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469568/how-to-sort-a-boxplot-by-the-median-values-in-pandas/19471613#19471613) but first you need to group your data and create a new data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
# this is probably a strange way to generate random data; please feel free to correct it
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": [random.choice(["A","B","C"]) for i in range(n)], 
                   "Y": [random.choice(["a","b","c"]) for i in range(n)],
                   "Z": [random.gauss(0,1) for i in range(n)]})
grouped = df.groupby(["X", "Y"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({col:vals['Z'] for col,vals in grouped})

meds = df2.median()
meds.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df2 = df2[meds.index]
df2.boxplot()

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I had to change: `meds.sort(ascending=False)` to `meds.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)` to make this work (Pandas 0.20.1, Python 3.6.1, Windows 8).

Comment: @StephenMcAteer Thanks for the tip. I'm not using the latest versions of Pandas so please feel free to edit the answer and add your version of the answer for future users.

Comment: Is there any way to have a backup sort for when medians are the same? For example, if two medians are the same then sort by one of the quartiles.

Answer (score 18):

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21913819/2997574) to Alvaro Fuentes' in function form for more portability

```
import pandas as pd

def boxplot_sorted(df, by, column):
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({col:vals[column] for col, vals in df.groupby(by)})
  meds = df2.median().sort_values()
  df2[meds.index].boxplot(rot=90)

boxplot_sorted(df, by=["X", "Y"], column="Z")
```

Answer (score 13):

To answer the question in the title, without addressing the extra detail of plotting all combinations of two categorical variables:

```
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category": [np.random.choice(["A","B","C","D"]) for i in range(n)],      
                   "Variable": [np.random.normal(0, 10) for i in range(n)]})

grouped = df.loc[:,['Category', 'Variable']] \
    .groupby(['Category']) \
    .median() \
    .sort_values(by='Variable')

sns.boxplot(x=df.Category, y=df.Variable, order=grouped.index)
```

[image]

I've added this solution because it is hard to reduce the accepted answer to a single variable, and I'm sure people are looking for a way to do that. I myself came to this question multiple time looking for such an answer.

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies with your minimal example (a missing ' after the first 'Category, switching from "X" and "Z" in the declaration to "Category" and "Variable" during grouping and plotting. But the overall idea behind it was useful for my seaborn-powered application.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Thanks for pointing those things out. That's what I get for not copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the accepted answer but ran into complications when I wanted to overlay a second plot that uses the other y axis (i.e. `ax.twinx()`). The issue is that the second plot's x-axis overwrites the sorted order.

I ended up doing the following with just `seaborn`. This is similar to @rocksNwaves's answer, but I am writing it with terminology introduced by question. **Just three steps:**

1. If you don't mind creating a column that combines "X" and "Y", it will make things easier with seaborn:

   ```py
   df["XY"] = df["X"] + df["Y"]
   ```

   Of course, you can combine the two columns in however way you want.
2. Order by XY and obtain sorted index

   ```
   grouped = df.groupby(["XY"])
   order = grouped.median()["Z"].sort_values().index
   ```
3. Plot using seaborn

   ```
   sns.boxplot(x="XY", y="Z", data=df, order=order)
   ```

   Note that you can think of `order` as specifying the order of labels on the x axis.

A complete program:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 100
# this is probably a strange way to generate random data; please feel free to correct it
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": [random.choice(["A","B","C"]) for i in range(n)],
                   "Y": [random.choice(["a","b","c"]) for i in range(n)],
                   "Z": [random.gauss(0,1) for i in range(n)]})

df["XY"] = df["X"] + df["Y"]
grouped = df.groupby(["XY"])
order = grouped.median()["Z"].sort_values().index
sns.boxplot(x="XY", y="Z", data=df, order=order, palette="light:#5A9")
plt.show()
```

`df` looks like

```
    X  Y         Z
0   A  a  0.894873
1   C  a -0.568682
2   C  b  0.985260
3   B  c  2.056287
...
```

The plot looks like

[image]