# How to order boxplot categories in x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a df with two columns, ACQUISITION_CHANNEL and HOURS_WORKED_CUMULATIVE which I am plotting as a jittered bar plot using the code below. I would like to sort the categories on the x axis so that they are ordered by the highest median first.

| ACQUISITION_CHANNEL | HOURS_WORKED_CUMULATIVE |
| --- | --- |
| Referral | 34 |
| Job Platform | 42 |
| Referral | 34 |
| Offline | 42 |
| Referral | 34 |
| Digital | 42 |

...

```
group = 'ACQUISITION_CHANNEL'
column = 'HOURS_WORKED_CUMULATIVE'
grouped = df.groupby(group)


names, vals, xs = [], [] ,[]

for i, (name, subdf) in enumerate(grouped):
    names.append(name)
    vals.append(subdf[column].tolist())
    xs.append(np.random.normal(i+1, 0.1, subdf.shape[0]))

plt.boxplot(vals, labels=names, showfliers=False )
ngroup = len(vals)
clevels = np.linspace(0., 1., ngroup)

for x, val, clevel in zip(xs, vals, clevels):
    plt.scatter(x, val, alpha=0.4, c='#1f77b4')

plt.title('Hours Worked by Acquisition Channel')
plt.xlabel('Acquisition Channel')
plt.ylabel('Total Hours Worked')
```

[image: Jittered box plot]

Comment: Do you have any example data?

Comment: @TomMcLean just added some example data in

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the construction by combining seaborn's [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and [`stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

group = 'ACQUISITION_CHANNEL'
column = 'HOURS_WORKED_CUMULATIVE'
df = pd.DataFrame({group: np.random.choice(['Referral', 'Job Platform', 'Offline', 'Digital'], 1000),
                   column: np.random.randint(10, 300, 1000) + np.random.randint(1, 30, 1000) ** 2})

x_order = df.groupby(group)[column].agg('median').sort_values(ascending=False).index
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=group, order=x_order, y=column,
                 palette=['skyblue'], medianprops={'color':'orange'})
sns.stripplot(data=df, x=group, order=x_order, y=column, jitter=0.4, alpha=0.6, ax=ax)
```

The stripplot can also be replaced by a `swarmplot`:

```py
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x=group, order=x_order, y=column, size=3, alpha=0.6, ax=ax)
```

[image: combined boxplot and stripplot or swarmplot]

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the data by median before plotting it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912634/how-can-i-sort-a-boxplot-in-pandas-by-the-median-values) has a good answer

```
meds = df2.median()
meds.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df2 = df2[meds.index]
df2.boxplot()
```